# Im trying to install pytermgui but it's stuck at: Using cached pytermgui-2.0.0.tar.gz (62 kB)

Tags: pip

I'm trying to install pytermgui to my VS code virtual environment but it gets stuck at Using cached pytermgui-2.0.0.tar.gz (62 kB)

Comment: Have you tried clearing the pip cache and have it redownload the source code?

Comment: I deleted my cache and not it's stuck at
Collecting pytermgui
  Downloading pytermgui-2.0.0.tar.gz (62 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 62.8/62.8 KB 834.8 kB/s eta 0:00:00